# Python3 での正規表現への変換について

Tags: python, 正規表現

Python3で `[xx-yy]` という形式で範囲を示した数（文字列）を、正規表現に変換するには、どのように記述すれば良いでしょうか？

入力例

```
hoge1 = '[10-20]'
hoge2 = '[0-100]'
hoge3 = '[23-94]'
```

期待する出力

```
hoge1 = '1[0-9]|20'
hoge2 = '[1-9]?[0-9]|100'
hoge3 = '2[3-9]|[3-8][0-9]|9[0-4]'
```

Comment: `'[10-20]' => '1[0-9]|20'` の場合、`'100'` や `'200'` などにもマッチしてしまいますが、それでよろしいですか？

Comment: `hoge2` の期待結果は `'[1-9]?[0-9]|100'` ではないのですか？それとも `'[0-9]?[0-9]|100`?

Comment: 面白いけれど、結構手強い処理だと思います。整数に変換して `min <= x <= max` のように数値的に比較する事で大抵の用はたせると思いますので、今すぐ片付けないといけない問題があるならば、そちらの線で進める事をお勧めします。

Comment: 期待する出力の形に制限があるのか、それとも単に使い物になる正規表現が得られればよいのかで回答も変わってくると思います。

Comment: すみません、`hoge2`の期待する出力を修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`min <= x <= max`で一先ず対応することにします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「期待する出力」を見て、右の桁から順に文字クラスにまとめるという意図らしいと思い、ざっくり書いてみました。Pythonらしい書き方になってないと思いますが、そこはご容赦を。

```
import re

def _parse_numrange(s):
    m = re.search(r'\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]', s)
    return m.group(1), m.group(2)

def _join_pos_digit(lst, p):
    lst2 = [lst[0]]             # 処理後のリスト
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if len(lst[i]) < p or len(lst[i - 1]) < p:
            # 比較する桁が存在しない
            lst2.append(lst[i])
            continue
        # lst中の前の値と当該桁を比較
        rst = lst[i][-(p - 1)] if p > 1 else []
        rst1 = lst[i - 1][-(p - 1)] if p > 1 else []
        if int(lst[i - 1][-p]) + 1 == int(lst[i][-p]) and rst == rst1:
            # 当該桁が前の値+1で、当該桁以降が同じなら、lst2でまとめる
            if isinstance(lst2[-1][-p], list):
                # lst2で当該桁をまとめ済み
                lst2[-1][-p].append(lst[i][-p])
            else:
                # lst2で当該桁はまだまとめていない
                lst2[-1][-p] = [lst2[-1][-p], lst[i][-p]]
        else:
            # lst2に追加
            lst2.append(lst[i])
    return lst2

def _check_head(lst):
    lst2 = [lst[0]]             # 処理後のリスト
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if len(lst[i]) == len(lst[i - 1]) + 1 and lst[i][1:] == lst[i - 1]:
            lst2[i - 1] = [lst[i][0], '?', *lst[i - 1]]
        else:
            lst2.append(lst[i])
    return lst2

def _lst2re(lst):
    lst2 = []
    for x in lst:
        s = ''
        for c in x:
            if isinstance(c, list):
                if len(c) > 2:
                    s = s + '[' + c[0] + '-' + c[-1] + ']'
                else:
                    s = s + '[' + c[0] + c[1] + ']'
            else:
                s = s + c
        lst2.append(s)
    return '|'.join(lst2)

def numrange2re(s):
    st, ed = _parse_numrange(s)
    # (数値 → 文字列 → 文字のリスト) のリスト
    lst = [list(str(x)) for x in range(int(st), int(ed) + 1)]
    # 右端の桁から [] にまとめる処理
    for p in range(1, len(ed) + 1):
        lst = _join_pos_digit(lst, p)
    # 左端の文字をチェックして x? にするところを探す
    lst =  _check_head(lst)
    # リスト → 正規表現文字列
    return _lst2re(lst)

print(numrange2re('[10-20]'))   #=> '1[0-9]|20'
print(numrange2re('[0-100]'))   #=> '[1-9]?[0-9]|100'
print(numrange2re('[23-94]'))   #=> '2[3-9]|[3-8][0-9]|9[0-4]'
```